# Bootstrap JavaScript in Webpack 5 - only working as ESM?

Tags: javascript, webpack

When importing Bootstrap JS components directly, the functionality doesn't fully work but no errors are shown in the console:

```
import Dropdown from 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown'
```

The method below works but includes all of bootstrap JS, even parts not being used

```
import { Dropdown } from 'bootstrap'
```

With the first import, I can see Popper positioning the dropdown when the toggle is clicked but nothing is displayed, and aria-expanded attribute doesn't toggle. Same result in webpack development/production mode. Manually instantiating the dropdown in JS also doesn't make any difference:

```
const myDropDown = Dropdown.getOrCreateInstance(myDropDownToggle);
```

What am I missing?

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm dist/*",
    "build-dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "stats": "webpack --profile --json > stats.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "10.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-tabs": "^6.0.0",
    "swiper": "^9.0.4",
    "toolcool-range-slider": "^4.0.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.10",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.2",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");

const config = {
    //cache: false,
    devtool: "source-map",
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        app: ['./js/index.js', './scss/index.scss'],
        admin: ['./js-admin/admin.js'],
        style: './js-admin/product-configurator/Styles/App.scss'
    },
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/,
        // These help on NTFS
        aggregateTimeout: 20,
        poll: 1000
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        publicPath: "auto",
        filename: 'js/[name].js',
        chunkFilename: "js/[name]_[chunkhash].js",
        assetModuleFilename: 'images/[hash][ext][query]'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            importLoaders: 2
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    // Defined in .babelrc.json
                    // options: {
                    //     presets: [
                    //         [
                    //             "@babel/preset-env", {
                    //                 targets: "defaults"
                    //             }
                    //         ],
                    //         "@babel/preset-react"
                    //     ]
                    // }
                },
            },
            {
                // Extract images
                test: /\.(webp|svg|png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            `...`,
            new CssMinimizerPlugin({
                minimizerOptions: {
                    preset: [
                        "default",
                        {
                            discardComments: {
                                removeAll: true
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            }),
        ],
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: "jQuery"
    },
    plugins: [
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            port: 3000,
            proxy: {
                target: "http://example.local"
            },
            files: [
                "wp-content/themes/theme/**/*.css",
                "wp-content/themes/theme/**/*.js",
                "wp-content/themes/theme/**/*.php"
            ],
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css/[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css",
            ignoreOrder: false,
        }),
    ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

**EDIT:**
I've found that if the ESM style import is used anywhere in my JavaScript (even if the file is not directly used), then all of the Bootstrap JS is imported/loaded. If both style imports are used, then it gets imported/loaded twice.

Not sure if that is intended behaviour.

Anyway, I've got it working by removing all occurrences of:

```
import { Dropdown } from 'bootstrap'
```

And only using the direct file imports instead:

```
import Dropdown from 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown'
```

Comment: _Bootstrap is dependent on jQuery and Popper, these are defined as peerDependencies, this means that you will have to make sure to add both of them to your package.json using npm install --save jquery popper.js._ from docs, have you done that?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Yes, popper is defined as a dependency in package.json. jQuery is not a dependency of Bootstrap 5, but jQuery is also available externally anyway.

Comment: You might want to look at [enabling tree-shaking in Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#conclusion), which would remove unused code, so you can use the default method and get the most out of ESM imports (well, actually the least). Not sure how cumbersome that is though. Might be easier to switch to Rollup...

Comment: @MoritzRingler Thanks I have previously read up on it but I am using @babel/preset-env so I guess that is changing everything to CommonJS. So maybe setting babel option "modules" to "umd" or false would fix it.
I would have though import { Dropdown } would only import the Dropdown

Comment: This approach (using the above mentioned `/dist/` modules) with Vite.js v4.4.5 (which uses Rollup.js internally) correctly trimmed my bundle output size.

I used `npx vite-bundle-visualizer` to validate that only the parts of Bootstrap.js (`bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip` in my case) were being included.

If I used `import { Tooltip } from 'bootstrap` then everything was included.